# Yii framework module layout issue

Tags: yii

I am creating my first framework based project using YII framework. I have a main site and a module based backend to manage the site(CMS). First I used the same layout for both ends, but now I want two different layouts for front end and backend. I changed my module layout by adding a layouts folder to the module view file and I added “$controller->layout = 'main';” to the base module file of my module folder. Now the layout has been changed but when I logged in as a admin to the backend I cannot view any admin controller action, it means I am just a guest user. This issue is solved when I change my layout to the main site layout. 
Please let me know if there is anything to do for this?

Comment: As you have mentioned that the layout is getting displayed but just that it shows you are a guest user, check the code where you must have written code like `Yii::app()->user->isGuest` to verify if the user is logged in or not.

Comment: No I tried same main.php code of the main site in my module layout. It doesn't work. As I said it works when I change the layout to the main site layout???

Answer (score 0):

if the backend and frontend you created like module I think this will help:

```
$this->layoutPath = Yii::getPathOfAlias('(application.views.layouts or path/to/layouts)');
```

and in controllers of module just pasting layout name:

```
public $layout = 'login';
```